# what happens when overloaded method has template class as parameter

Tags: c++, templates, overloading

C++ allows us to write generic functions using Templates. And it also has the feature of function overloading.

I have written the following program:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
template <typename T>
void test(T a)
{
    cout<<"using template";    
}
void test(int a)
{
    cout<<"using int";
}
int main()
{

   test(10);
   return 0;
}
```

it's out put is:

```
using int
```

I want to know that on what basis that particular method is getting selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A non-template function is a better match than a function template.

Reference (C++ Draft Standard N3337):

> **13.3.3 Best viable function**
>
> ...
>
> Given these definitions, a viable function F1 is defined to be a better function than another viable function F2 if for all arguments i, ICSi(F1) is not a worse conversion sequence than ICSi(F2), and then
>
> ...
>
> — F1 is a non-template function and F2 is a function template specialization, or, if not that,
>
> — F1 and F2 are function template specializations, and the function template for F1 is more specialized
> than the template for F2 according to the partial ordering rules described in 14.5.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

Its obvious behavior, actual param matching with formal. As template is concerned the compiler doesn't know what type is T, also call to template function has different syntax.

Comment: so, at runtime Firstly,it finds the prototype with exact datatype. if it doesn't find it then it goes for parameter type T. right?

Comment: wrong, if params match the function gets called (there is weak type-checking between numeric types), runtime even compiler doesnot know that T goanna be int, you explicitly have to mention T is int in function call.